# How to point Multiple Domains at an Azure Windows VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, virtual-machine, hosting

I have been looking for the answer to this but unable to find it thus far.

I have an Azure Windows VM with 3 Websites on it. I have managed to configure one domain to point at the IP Address of the Server (A Record) but when I try to point domains to the other two sites, I cannot specify the port number.

How would I go about getting additional custom domains to point at different ports on my VM?

Thanks! Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map different domains to ports.

What you can do, is map domains to specific sites on IIS and have them listen to that specific hostname. Godaddy has a guide on how to do that [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7620/adding-a-domain-name-in-microsoft-iis-7)

Comment: This worked. To clarify, all you need to do is point the Domains to the IP Address of the Server (A Name Record) and then in IIS you add a binding to the IIS Website on Port 80. Just make sure to add the domains (both with the www. and one without).

Comment: You don't necessarily have to point them to the IP (A Record). A CNAME will work just fine as well, which unless you have a Reserved IP Address requested from Azure, it's the best approach. You still run the risk of changing an IP and effectively break your DNS records if you don't use a Reserved IP or a CNAME.